# Icons for Windows Executable with multiple resolutions

Tags: windows, visual-studio

When I add a multi-resolution-icon file to my Windows application in Visual Studio 2013 it seems Windows and/or VS ignores the resolution and it seems the 32x32x24bit icon is used for the task-bar. My icon file contains the following resolutions: 16x16,32x32,48x48,256x256 with 8-bit and 24-bit each. The application itself is DPI-unaware but expected that an appropriate icon is used though. Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There are very particular specifications for what formats should be present in your icon resources if you want Windows to use them properly.  If you don't follow their recommendations you will get very inconsistent results from your application.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dn742485(v=vs.85).aspx has the guidelines you will want.

> Application icons and Control Panel items: The full set includes
> 16x16, 32x32, 48x48, and 256x256 (code scales between 32 and 256). The .ico file format is required. For Classic Mode, the full set is 16x16,
> 24x24, 32x32, 48x48 and 64x64.
>
> List item icon options: Use live
> thumbnails or file icons of the file type (for example, .doc); full
> set.
>
> Toolbar icons: 16x16, 24x24, 32x32. Note that toolbar icons are
> always flat, not 3D, even at the 32x32 size.
>
> Dialog and wizard icons:
> 32x32 and 48x48.
>
> Overlays: Core shell code (for example, a shortcut)
> 10x10 (for 16x16), 16x16 (for 32x32), 24x24 (for 48x48), 128x128 (for
> 256x256). Note that some of these are slightly smaller but are close
> to this size, depending on shape and optical balance.
>
> Quick Launch
> area: Icons will scale down from 48x48 in Alt+Tab dynamic overlays,
> but for a more crisp version, add a 40x40 to .ico file.
>
> Balloon icons:
> 32x32 and 40x40.
>
> Additional sizes: These are useful to have on hand as
> resources to make other files (for example, annotations, toolbar
> strips, overlays, high dpi, and special cases): 128x128, 96x96, 64x64,
> 40x40, 24x24, 22x22, 14x14, 10x10, and 8x8. You can use .ico, .png,
> .bmp, or other file formats, depending on code in that area.

Comment: No matter which ico file I use in my application (as resource) it's always the low-resolution icon. I forgot to mention that I have problems with the application icon in the task bar. The icon in the explorer-view is fine though.

Comment: Can you post a link to your icon file? I'd like to take a look at it.  Also, what did you use to create the icon?

Comment: I used Axialis IconWorkshop trial but also tried icons like this one here which seems to contain all necessary resolutions. As mentioned, the icon file looks great, its just lacking in the taskbar where a lower resolution is used (looks like 32x32) http://www.iconarchive.com/download/i83704/custom-icon-design/mono-general-3/home.ico

Comment: That icon file is working fine for me on Win8.1 / default DPI / normal taskbar buttons.  What version of Windows are you using and have you modified your DPI settings or set the taskbar to use "small buttons"?  Also, are you sure you set the same icon on the project as well as the form?

Comment: Here are some interesting news. When I dock the application into the taskbar via drag&drop it gets the high-resolution image. When I start it manually (and the application was not docked before into the task-bar!) it gets the lower resolution. Same for applications like Skype. Applications like Chrome seem to always get a high-resolution image in the task-bar, no matter how its started. The size of my Win8.1 is set to 150%.

Comment: I get the slight impression that my application needs to be DPI sytem and/or monitor aware which is then reflected in the icons. I check this via Process Explorer and this seem to match pretty good.

Comment: It is not an issue with your application. The app does not need to be aware. Looks like some windows bugs or quirks cause this. This thread has a bunch of different workarounds you can try http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-performance/in-windows-7-some-icons-in-the-system-tray/499977eb-6c7e-e011-9b4b-68b599b31bf5