# How to specify icon for Win10+ Task Manager / Apps tab

Tags: c#, winforms, icons, taskmanager

I am unable to specify icon for Win10+ Task Manager / Apps tab / main item.
Created a new WinForms app (.net framework 4.x / VS2019).

Specified Form icon in GUI Designer --> this appears in the Task Manager / Apps / sub-item. Also in the Form title bar - **Fine**.

Specified App icon in VS/Project settings --> this appears in the Windows Explorer (.exe icon) list, also in file Properties window. - **Fine**.

So all fine, except Task Manager / Apps tab / main item --> still uses some default icon, which I don't know how to change?

Adding a picture for the sake of clarity:

[image]

I checked all relevant SO / other resources, no success (or does not work/apply to this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it looks like Explorer caches icons (in `C:\Users\<USER>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Explorer\*.db`). If I kill explorer + taskmgr + all other which locks these files, then delete these files, then restart explorer, the proper icon will appear in taskmgr too.
Maybe Windows restart could be enough, I have not tried that.
**The answer**:  Task Manager / Apps tab / main item -> the App Project settings / icon what appears there.

Answer (score 2):

My guess is, that this is not a coding issue, instead an issue with you `*.ico` file.

Icon files contain multiply images for diffrent resolutions. The OS picks the image with the [correct size according to its own specifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29323398/icons-for-windows-executable-with-multiple-resolutions).

In Windows I would make sure your Icon file contains Images in following sizes:

- 16x16, 24x24, 32x32, 48x48, 64x64 and 256x256

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/vis-icons

Task Manager will probably pick one of them to display and since the required resolution is not available in your ICO file, it displays the fallback Icon.

Comment: Thanks, good idea, but did not help.   
I modified the icon file to have all resolutions (although 8bits only, I did not do all permutations of res*bit, only one 24bit I tried 16x16x24bit, which is the size of the icons on the screen in TaskManager (I measured).
See: [link](https://i.ibb.co/0MDJcnJ/icon2.png)

Comment: Update: I tried with other icon files (from other apps, not mine, where they seem to work), 32bit BMP format with all resolutions and also 32bit PNG format with all resolutions - and no success. The form icon, the explorer icon, etc all works, except Task Manager.

Comment: Update2: it works! Sort of...  But I don't know exactly how. I read (for other topics) about some caching of icons, so I killed explorer and also restarted Task Manager => and voila, there we go, the 32bit icon appeared in taskmgr. So I wanted to figure out which resolution/bit is displayed, but since then, whenever I kill/restart explorer/taskmgr, it just shows the old icon which appeared once. Cannot change anymore. Maybe need to restart windows? So getting on slowly...

Comment: Ok, even the 16x16x8bit icon appears. All are just cached... I will make an answer.